# My Ubuntu locks on black screen due to idleness

Tags: 20.04, suspend

When my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS stays idle for a time (Cooking a meal duration) I find it locked into a black screen and cannot open it even when I press all the keys on computer. So everytime I have to shut it down using power button and start again to see my desktop. Caffeine extension does not help.

Comment: This is a temporary solution, you may workaround it by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F2 then login then type command `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions` and then hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or was it Ctrl+Alt+F7 ?)

Comment: Any of the solutions does not seem to be working

Comment: Then please add a lot of information about your system like lspci, lsusb, lshw, lscpu; and whether it's a laptop or pc, manufacturer, model, etc